# element of object_list in script section of django template

Tags: python, django, templates

my view returns the `object_list` to the template. I apply a `for` loop to this list and everything works fine. But when I write some Javascript inside `script` tags just below a button and try to get `{{ post.pk }}` inside script tags, it returns the pk of the last element in `object_list`. For example: if it is the first iteration and when above `script` tags I try to get `{{ post.pk }}`, it returns the pk of the current element of object_list. But when I try to do the same thing between script tags, it returns the pk of the last element of object_list.
What is the reason and is there any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript has no *access* to the list. After rendering the response, it is just a stream of HTML (or something else) in the response. It might however help to show *what* you aim to do. Likely there is a solution to pass a list of primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
<script>
  var object_list = [
  {% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  ];
</script>
```

Display the source or use an alert() to make sure the list is correct.